# Closure: why doesn't an object get inlined?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I've been having an issue with the closure compiler - sometimes it'll inline the contents of a structure and sometimes not. For instance:

```
(function(){
  const C = {SOMETHING: 0x76, BLA: 123}

  function Test(write) {
    write(5+C.BLA);
  }

  exports.hello = function() {
    return Test;
  };
})()
```

Does not inline:

```
(function(){function a(b){b(5+c.BLA)}var c={SOMETHING:118,BLA:123};exports.hello=function(){return a}})();
```

But simply changing the way `Test` is exported:

```
(function(){
  const C = {SOMETHING: 0x76, BLA: 123}

  function Test(write) {
    write(5+C.BLA);
  }

  exports.hello = Test;
})()
```

Will cause it to inline fine:

```
(function(){exports.hello=function(a){a(128)}})();
```

I'm using SIMPLE_OPTIMISATIONS here, but ADVANCED_OPTIMISATIONS doesn't improve matters, nor does type annotation:

```
(function(){
  /** @enum {number} */
  const C = {/** @const */SOMETHING: 0x76, /** @const */BLA: 123}

  function Test(write) {
    write(5+C.BLA);
  }

  exports.hello = function() {
    return Test;
  };
})()
```

Any idea why it wouldn't be inlining? And is there a way to get a report or find out from the compiler?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Local property inlining is pretty conservative.  That it will only inline if it is trivial to determine that the value is defined before it is used.  However because of the function hoisting the function definition is ordered before the object literal and thus the function references the object before it is defined (even though it can't be called before, the pass doesn't track that).

Changing the function definition from:

`function Test() {...}`

to

`const Test = function() {...}`

allows the compiler to inline it.  This reduces your code sample to:

```
(function() {
  var b = function(a) {
    a(128);
  };
  exports.hello = function() {
    return b;
  };
})();
```

You can see the result here:

https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%252Cprint_input_delimiter%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A(function()%257B%250A%2520%2520const%2520C%2520%253D%2520%257BSOMETHING%253A%25200x76%252C%2520BLA%253A%2520123%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520const%2520Test%2520%253D%2520function(write)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520write(5%252BC.BLA)%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520exports.hello%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520Test%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%253B%250A%257D)()